# Pandas read_sql reading Access Database: First row missing

Tags: python, sql, pandas, ms-access

I have an external database, pre MS Access 2007 that I am connecting to with pypyodbc and converting to dataframe with pandas. That by itself seems to work ok, however, the first line of data seems to be missing.

```
import pypyodbc
import pandas as pd
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};'
    r'DBQ=c:\path_to_my.mdb;'
    )

cnxn = pypyodbc.connect(conn_str)
data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY date DESC",cnxn)
cnxn.close()
#print a few lines and only specific columns   
   print(data.loc[:,('date','time')].head())
```

As a result I get

[image]

as my first line. The first entry in row 0 is from 04:00 o'clock.
In the databse itself, however, I have a more recent entry from 06:00

[image]

Why is the first line omitted in my read?

Comment: In the meastime I found that when I delete the sorting from the SQL statement and sort the dataframe with pandas, then all data is present. It would be intersting to know where it goes wrong in the SQL statement

Comment: It is possibly due to there being a "date" part of the time field - your example has "1899-12-30". Also, note that `date` is a reserved word in Access, so needs to be wrapped in square brackets (`ORDER BY [date] DESC;`) or else replaced.

Comment: It looks like the date part and the time part are in two separate columns (fields). Is that the case?

Comment: @GordThompson yes correct. The funky 1899 year comes from the conversion from Access time to pandas datetime. I think Excel /Access etc. count every day as an integer, starting from 01.01.1900. Basically I use the date stamp from column 0 and merge it with time from column 1 to get the actual timestamp. The filtering is done on column 0 only. As Applecore  mentioned, date is a reserved word. My actual DB is in a different language, I'm actually filtering in German "Datum". Not sure if foreign language words are also reserved, but I think they are not.