# Pandas read_sql columns incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.8

read sql:

```
data = pd.read_sql_query(f'select * from {db}.{table}', con=self.engine)
```

but return:

[image]

The first row becomes the column name. If I set columns, the value of the first row of the query result will be lost

I didn't have any problems before. I don't know why there are problems now. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is worth mentioning which database technology you are reading from, and also taking a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282891/pandas-read-sql-reading-access-database-first-row-missing) to see if there are any similarities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I use `clickhouse` database, I read correctly through `read_sql_table`, but use read_ sql cannot correctly return the column name I expect

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a [known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56706629/clickhouse-does-not-return-column-headers) and unresolved incompatibility between pandas and clickhouse. [pandahouse](https://github.com/kszucs/pandahouse) might resolve this for you, and [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65633799/4251738) may also help.